# how to use fetch without using success in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Just started learning Backbone JS.

Below code getting correct output for me in console.

**CODE 1:**

```
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'api/todos'
    });

    var todoItem = new TodoItem({id:1});
    todoItem.fetch({

        success: function(todoItem){

            console.log(todoItem.get('description'));

            var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
                render: function(){
                    var html = '<h3>'+this.model.get('description')+'</h3>';
                    this.$el.html(html);
                }
            });
            var todoView = new TodoView({model:todoItem });
            todoView.render();
            console.log(todoView.el);
            }

    });
```

But for below code, iam getting output as 'undefined' in console.

**CODE 2:**

```
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'api/todos'
    });

var todoItem = new TodoItem({id:1});
todoItem.fetch();


var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
render: function(){
    var html = '<h3>'+this.model.get('description')+'</h3>';
    this.$el.html(html);
}
});
var todoView = new TodoView({model:todoItem });
todoView.render();
console.log(todoView.el);
```

I knew the reason why iam getting as 'undefined' in **CODE 2**, BUT in **CODE 1**, how do I use '**fetch**' without using '**success**'? ( Currently  my entire **view code** forcibly to write inside 'success', which iam not interested to write in that way. )

Answer (score 0):

the `fetch` returns a promise object, you can make your code cleaner by following

```js
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'api/todos'
});

var renderTodoView = function(todoItem) {
  console.log(todoItem.get('description'));
  var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
      var html = '<h3>' + this.model.get('description') + '</h3>';
      this.$el.html(html);
    }
  });
  var todoView = new TodoView({
    model: todoItem
  });
  todoView.render();
  console.log(todoView.el);
}

var todoItem = new TodoItem({
  id: 1
});
todoItem
  .fetch()
  .done(renderTodoView);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### As said, one method is to use the promise returned by the `fetch` call. When doing this:

*note that if you don't bind the context of `this.render` to `this` it will map it to an unexpected object, depending on the runtime environment, usually the global scope.*

```
todoItem.fetch().done(_.bind(this.render, this));
```

#### Another options is to use `listenToOnce` on the "sync" event:

```js
todoItem.fetch();
this.listenToOnce(todoItem, 'sync', this.render);
```